# Sampling points on a face of a human body mesh

Tags: sampling, shape-analysis

Is there a known shape analysis technique to sample points of a not necessarily naked human body mesh (more specifically the head part).

The goal would be to randomly sample (uniform distribution) vertices of the head part of the mesh and do some PCA analysis on those points. I know in the ML literature there're techniques to reconstruct human body etc, but I wonder if there's maybe a technique which is not ML based for this specific problem.

Comment: not quite sure what you want to sample here? How does one "sample the head"?

Comment: I think you got what I want to sample (i.e. vertices on the head). My first approach would have been detecting features on the mesh (not sure which feature detector though). Some of those features would probably be around region of interest (maybe nose? even that would suffice), I can probably then cluster based on coordinates.

Comment: And the "how" is the actual question.

Comment: Sorry, I honestly didn't get that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've changed a bit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I am assuming this is image processing in that you intend to say you are sampling an image of a human head?

Comment: No, it's a 3D shape analysis problem (without images).